# sort from data by using username?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a login screen with username and password, i have saved username to a variable by using service.(let it be getservice.usrname)

i have a list of data, im printing whole data in next page using ng-repeat. what i want is, to print detais of a perticular person, that is filter with user name.

```
    [{
"username": "vishnu",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
"task": "fixing bugs",
"time": "1"
 }, {
"username": "seenu",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
"task": "working on ui",
"time": "2"
    }, {
"username": "sam",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "bigiron",
"task": "working on api",
"time": "5"
  },
   {
"username": "vishnu",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 03 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "timetracker",
"task": "ui designing",
"time": "1"
 }]
```

Comment: it worked, but simple methods are there.... see the answer...by abid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple in angularJS, here is example code,

In controller,

```
 $scope.list=  [{
    "username": "vishnu",
    "FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
    "task": "fixing bugs",
    "time": "1"
     }, {
    "username": "seenu",
    "FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
    "task": "working on ui",
    "time": "2"
        }, {
    "username": "sam",
    "FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "selectedProject": "bigiron",
    "task": "working on api",
    "time": "5"
      },
       {
    "username": "vishnu",
    "FromDate": "Wed Mar 03 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "selectedProject": "timetracker",
    "task": "ui designing",
    "time": "1"
  }]
```

and in HTML file,

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="u in list| filter:{username:'vishnu'}">
      // print your items
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Here is plnkr example. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/gtfikICLQFeGgrgV7I0i?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

A classic angular solution, would be to use [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Somthing like that:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="query">
<div ng-repeat="user in ctrl.data | filter:query">
 <ul>
        <li>{{user.username}}</li>
        <li>{{user.task}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

see: https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/7a7f48o3/